# Find the point of intersection of a plane

Tags: parametric-functions

I would like to determine the point of intersection of a line which crosses a plane. If I were to do it by hand, I would proceed as follows:

1. Find the parametric representation for line $r(t) = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ $t(x_1-x_0, y_1-y_0,z_1-z_0)$
2. Sub into the plane equation
3. Solve for (t)
4. Find point of intersection

How can I do this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Please add working code to make reproduction of your problem possible. Otherwise answering will be difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
   planeEqn = 2 x - 3 y + 7 == 0;
   pt = {-1, 4, 2};
   dir = {3, 3, -1};
   r[t_] := pt + t dir

   t1 = t /. First@Solve[planeEqn /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> r[t]], t]
(* -7/3 *)
   r[t1]
(* {-8, -3, 13/3} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[n_, pip_, p1_, p2_] := 
  p1 t + (1 - t) p2 /. First@Solve[(t p1 + (1 - t) p2).n == pip.n, t];
int2[{p1_, p2_, p3_}, {p4_, p5_}] := 
 int[Cross[p2 - p1, p3 - p1], p1, p4, p5]
```

With `int`, `n` is normal to plane and `pip` is point in plane, `p1` and `p2` define line. `int2`uses `{p1,p2,p3}` as three points in plane and `{p4,p5}` points defining the line. A line in the plane will return the line. When there is no intersection an error will be thrown. I leave it to interested party to correct (and clean to deal with degenerate specifications).

For fun (and to illustrate use of `InfinitePlane`,`InfiniteLine`,`RegionIntersection`):

```
DynamicModule[{r = RandomReal[{0, 5}, {2, 3}], 
  s = RandomReal[{0, 5}, {3, 3}]},
 Grid[{{Dynamic@Button["Line", r = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {2, 3}]], 
    Dynamic@Row[{"r[t]=", Simplify[t r[[1]] + (1 - t) r[[2]] ]}]},
   {Dynamic@Button["Plane", s = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {3, 3}]], 
    Dynamic[Simplify[
      Cross[s[[1]] - s[[2]], s[[1]] - s[[3]]].({x, y, z} - s[[1]]) == 
       0]]}, {Dynamic@
     Graphics3D[{InfinitePlane[s], {Blue, Thick, 
        InfiniteLine[r]}, {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[int2[s, r]]}}, 
      PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Medium], 
    Dynamic[int2[s, r]]}
   , {"Region Intersection", 
    Dynamic@RegionIntersection[InfinitePlane[s], InfiniteLine[r]]}}, 
  Frame -> All]]
```

[image]